# How to extract from string between the last 2 "symbol use REGEXP_SUBSTR in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

the string is like this

```
a:3:{s:8:"ref_type";s:4:"user";s:3:"tid";s:18:"TXID17073204182661";s:7:"message";s:19:"3757000431691375718";}
```

I want to get only the text between the last 2 ", which is 3757000431691375718

I have tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR(wml.data, '[^:]+$')` but this will return "3757000431691375718";}
Anyone can help?
Thank you

Comment: ``SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wml.data, '"', -2), '"', 1)``. Or REGEXP_SUBSTR usage is compulsory?

Comment: I have tried this, but it is not working on my side, do you have any idea using REGEXP_SUBSTR? or SUBSTR?

Comment: use `LEFT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(wml.data, '[^:]+$'), LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(wml.data, '[^:]+$')) - 3)` OR `SubStr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(wml.data, '[^:]+$'), 2, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(wml.data, '[^:]+$')) - 3)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working, but is it ok to exclude the " symbol?  and seem it is not working if the string is in another language or not number@Sudipto Bhattacharya

Comment: *but it is not working on my side* ?? https://dbfiddle.uk/a2ezBVAO

Comment: On my end, yes, I am using mysql by the way, is that the reason?@Akina

Comment: Or `REGEXP_REPLACE(@data, '^(.*")([^"]+)("[^"]+)$', '$2')` https://dbfiddle.uk/BdPKobc9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this pattern :

```
SELECT *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '(?<=\")[^"]+(?="[^"]*$)')
FROM mytable
```

The pattern matches:

```
(?<=\") Assert a " to the left
[^"]+ Match 1+ occurrences of any char except "
(?="[^"]*$) Assert a " to the right, followed by any char except "
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/C6XwhPzw)